# Battery between liftimes

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions, improper-integrals

Suppose that the operating lifetime of a certain type of battery is an exponential random variable with $\theta$ $= 2$ (measured in years). Find the probability that a battery of this type will have an operating lifetime of between 1 and 3 years.

My attempt:

> First:

$f(t)=(1/2)e^{-t/2}$ for $1<t<3$

$$P(T>1) = \int_1^{\infty} f(t) dt$$

$$P(T>1) = 1-\int_0^{1} (1/2)e^{-t/2} dt$$

$$P(T>1) =1+e^{-t/2}|1,0 $$
$$P(T>1) = 1+e^{-\frac{-1}{2}}-e^{0} =1+e^{-1/2} -1 = e^{-1/2} $$

> Then

$f(t)=(1/2)e^{-t/2}$ for $1<t<3$

$$P(T>3) = \int_3^{\infty} f(t) dt$$

$$P(T>3) = 1-\int_0^{3} (1/2)e^{-t/2} dt$$

$$P(T>3) =1+e^{-t/2}|3,0 $$
$$P(T>3) = 1+e^{-\frac{-3}{2}}-e^{0} =1+e^{-3/2} -1 = e^{-3/2} $$

> Now

$e^{-1/2}-e^{-3/2}=.38340$

I was thinking is this the correct way to solve this problem. Can someone please help correct this if the working is wrong? Can someone also please show me a simpler way if possible?

Comment: You could just calculate $\int_1^3 f(t)\,dt$. The same as yours essentially, but fewer computations.

Comment: Looks fine. It is useful to make the equality $P\{T>x\}=e^{-\lambda x}$ (for exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$) a part of your mathematical luggage. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution.